# What return computerPick[randomPick] in this case do?

Tags: javascript, return

Noob here. For some reason, I just couldn't understand what the [randomPick] dose. Isn't returning computerPick enough?

```
function computerPlay() {
computerPick = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
randomPick = [Math.floor(Math.random() *computerPick.length)];
return computerPick[randomPick]; }
```

Comment: It randomly selects one value from array.

Answer (score 0):

So here you have a list of moves and you want to choose one of them at random.

If you returned `computerPick`, then you would be returning a list of 3 moves, which is not what you want.

`Math.random()` will pick a number greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1. So you get a fraction. Hence you multiply it with the length of your array to scale it up.

Say you got a random number `r`

> 0 <= r < 1

Your array length is 3. So,

> 0 <= 3r < 3

But this could be a fraction, say `2.3`. Now you can't have fractional indices.

So you take the floor of it which will convert 2.3 to 2.

> floor(3r) = 0 or 1 or 2

Hence you will get a number 0 or 1 or 2 at random since the base `r` was random. And so the function will return a random move.